# Publishing issue with Binary files after upgrade from 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2011, 2013-sp1, publishing, deployer, binary

We have upgraded the Tridion CMS from 2011 SP1 to 2013 SP1.
We are facing one issue with Binary file which are not getting deployed on production environment.
Same thing is working on staging environment.
We are not getting any error while publishing but images are not going to specified folder.
We can see that deployment package contains the images but not deploying on file system in website's image folder.
[image]

Publishing is getting success for staging and production environment.[image]

I have checked MSDTC settings, permission on folder,publication properties,image path, compared target types (staging and live), tried replacing jar files from staging environment where everything is working fine, item type mapping also copied from staging environment.
I could not find any relevant information or error log in the cd_deployer.log or cd_core.log files. 
Attaching the item type mapping for the deployer cd_storage_conf.xml file. 
[image: item type mapping]
Note:- We are using single CMS for staging and production environment.

Comment: Can you post your cd_storage_conf.xml?

Comment: @Raimond I have attached the item type mapping from cd_storage_conf.xml file. Is it fine or should i post the complete cd_storage_conf.xml file?

Comment: Good start to debugging is catching publishing packages and checking what it contains. You can catch packages on staging and live and compare them and check for any differences. :)

Comment: Are your logs set to debug? do they (or the Event System) show anything at all?

Comment: @MarkoMilic Compared packages from both environments, look same. No difference found.

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders Yes logs are set to DEBUG mode but i did not find any error or relevant information related to binary publishing.Also in Event viewer logs, there is no error. Only information logs are there.

Comment: @Sumit is there a brokerFile Storage config? Is there a Root element inside that config? And can the deployer write to it?

Comment: @Raimond There is not any separate brokerFile storage config file.

Comment: I know - it should be in the same cd_storage_conf.xml ;). It looks something like this:    <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="brokerFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="c:\temp" />
   </Storage>

Comment: @Raimond Yes, there is a tag with brokerFile and it has root element like this:-<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="brokerFile">
    <Root Path="F:\Websites\tourism\DynamicData" />
   </Storage>

Comment: @Sumit, Based on the above configuration; you are telling the Tridion to store all binaries at defaultFile. Do you have an entry for defaultFile similar to the above in your storage.conf? The above comment shows an entry for brokerFile.

Comment: @Shiva Yes I do have an entry for defaultFile as well. Only difference is of path.

Comment: Make sure website folder has right permissions to website app pool.
Mask the credentials and can you post the full cd_storage.config?

Comment: @Sumit, Do you have deployer service installed or using httpupload for publishing?

Comment: @Mayank I checked on CD server and found that deployer service and httpupload both the things are configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumit, I had gone through with your question and comments again and I came to below conclusion:-

1. You should only use httpupload as deployer instead of deployer windows service. Kindly stop the deployer service and try publishing by httpupload only. There might be conflict with the both, please check if logs are generating on both the sides.
2. Also in your cd_storage_conf.xml file there is inconsistency in letter cases. Somewhere you are using small "i" in item tag and somewhere capital "I". Because XML is case sensitive so you should use  and  in this way. 

   You can refer the sample cd_storage_conf.xml file which came with the Tridion Installation media.

   Thanks

Comment: Hi Meyank,
I have stopped the deployer service and compare my cd_storage_conf.xml file with sample file.
I changed the tags as mentioned by you and tried to publish the binaries again and got success as I wanted.
Also I had to update the Binary mapping publication wise like typemapping for Pages as shown in above screenshot.
I could find logs for httpupload and deployer service separately. So might be there is some conflict between them.
Thanks for your response.